# Find minimum cost of calculating Squared sum

Tags: java, algorithm

How to approach below problem?

> Given an array of integer, the squared sum is defined as the sum of
>   squares of all elements. Given that the cost of changing element x of
>   array to y is (x-y)^2 and element once changed cannot be changed
>   again. Change the given array elements to get the desired squared sum.

For example :

> - Suppose array is {3,3,1} and desired squared sum is 6. Than we can change 3 to 1 and next 3 to 2 so the array becomes {1,2,1} or {2, 1,
>     1} and 1^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 6 i.e desired sum and the cost of change is
>     (3-2)^2 + (3-1)^2 = 5.

Comment: "Suppose array is {3,3,1} and desired squared sum is 6.". I don't understand why?

Comment: These are the requirements.

Comment: A few people have looked at this ... perhaps you can explain why you can change 3 to 1 but the second 3 is changed to 2.  Wouldn't changing it to 1 give a lower score? If so, can all values to be changed to 1?

Comment: No, because 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 != 6. You can change all values to whatever you want (at different costs). This is an optimization problem.

Comment: The same teacher? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601433/

Comment: It's understandable!! He has the array {3,3,2} woth square sum 3^2+3^2+2^2 = 22 .. and he said he wanted to change that array with the result 6 .. it's the new array {1,2,1} because 1^2+2^2+1^2 = 6 .. well, what is the result of square sums of new array {3,3,2} - {1,2,1} = {2,1,0}? it's 2^2+1^2 = 5

Comment: This is a quadratic programm. You could use the Gradient descent or the Interior point method for example.

Comment: I downvoted, because: You didn't either show us an approach nor is your problem well explained. This is not the right place to just spam your homework (or any other plain exercises).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to rephase the question.

You start with a point in N-dimensional space e.g. {3, 3, 1}, find the closest point of all the set of integer points which have a distance from the origin of sqrt(6) (or a sum of squares of 6)

Assuming this is the case, you could;

- determine all the permutation of integer points which have desired distance.
- find all the matching values e.g. in this case 1 is in the initial point and the possible solution.
- find the dimension which most closely matches an available value, starting from the largest first.
- repeat until you have found the closest matching value.

This should give you the smallest possible solution.  To confirm this you could explore all possible match using brute force.